# Android Studio Supported PCM Encoding Formats

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, record, audiorecord

I am trying to record Audio using the `AudioRecord` class with different sample rates and  PCM encodings, the problem is, when constructing the `AudioRecord` object and implementing the `AudioRecorder.getMinBufferSize()` method using `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT` or `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT`, different errors are reported such as:

> Unsupported sample encoding. Should be
>    ENCODING_PCM_8BIT
>    or ENCODING_PCM_16BIT.

or

> E/android.media.AudioRecord: getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.

The thing is, I am testing on a Moto G first generation with Lollipop, so according to the Android Developer documentation `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT` is supported.
Apparently `AudioRecorder.getMinBufferSize()` only works with `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT`.

So how am I supposed to know the MinBufferSize to implement on the constructor?

AudioRecord constructor:

```
audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(audioSource, sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat, mBufferSize);
```

AudioRecord method:

```
mBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AudioRecord` and `AudioTrack` are 2 different things.

`AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT` is supported by `AudioTrack` since `Lollipop`

But `AudioRecord` supports `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT` only since `Marshmallow`.

Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat.html.

[image]

Comment: Ok so  I guess no float recording for Lollipop yet, how about ENCODING_PCM_8BIT?, thank you for your quick answer

Comment: You can use any of these - ENCODING_PCM_8BIT or ENCODING_PCM_16BIT